# Why does my App show up as incompatible for google play store on samsung device?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am using a samsung galaxy tab4 running version 4.2.2 and i'm getting an app not compatible with device error.

This is my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/AppLogo" android:label="Catalyst"></application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME_ZONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REORDER_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ORIENTATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SURFACE_FLINGER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.EXPAND_STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FORCE_BACK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PERSISTENT_ACTIVITY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STATUS_BAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added support for android:xlargeScreens ? if not you can do so with the following inside the android manifest

```
<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true"
              android:normalScreens="true"
              android:largeScreens="true"
              android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Comment: The number of devices compatible in the google playstore remained the same after this change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the tablet can vibrate. Try switch the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

to:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vibrate" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: When I did this change in the manifest file the supported device went to 0 in the Google Play Store

Comment: I contacted Google Play Store support and the response was:

Comment: After an investigation of your app's manifest, I've discovered it includes
the autofocus permission. Since the Samsung Galaxy Tab3 does not support
the autofocus feature, your app won't be compatible with these devices
(both sizes of the tablets).